# Display 2e-3 as 2*10^-3 in Python

Tags: python

is it in Python possible to print floats like 2*10^-3 instead of 2e-3?

```
s = str(2e-3)
s.replace("e","*10^")
```

did not work.

Comment: Please replace `s = str(2e-3)` to `s = str('2e-3')`.

Comment: print where? to the console using `print`?

Answer (score 1):

Use format to get a string representing the number in scientific notation, and then replace 'e'

```
 s = '{:.2e}'.format(any_number).replace("e", "*10^")
```

the `.2` in `{:.2e}` asks for two decimal places so if `any_number==0` you get 0.00*10^+00 and for 0.002, 2.00*10^-03.

If you want to handle special cases you can split the formatted string into the mantissa and exponent strings and then, for example, remove a leading '+' and zero from the exponent

```
 ms,es='{:.2e}'.format(any_number).split('e')
 if len(es)==3 and es[1]=='0': es = es[0] + es[2]
 es = es.replace('+','')
 s = ms + '*10^' + es
```

Answer (score -1):

The mistake is that replace does not change `s`. So `s = s.replace...` fixes everything. Finally it should simply look like this, where the print part is optional:

```
s = str("2e-3")
s = s.replace("e", "*10^")
print(s)
```

with the output:

```
2*10^-3
```

Comment: So you're saying that `'0.002'.replace('e', '*10^')` somehow produces `2*10^-3`? It doesn't. Your answer doesn't answer your own question.

Answer (score -3):

Plase use `s = str('2e-3')`.

For `s = str(2e-3)`, i will calculate `2e-3`, the result will be a flaot, then convert the result to `string`.